# Why does $(\forall y)({\sim}Exy)$ have no quantifier-free equivalent statement?

Tags: logic, quantifiers, first-order-logic

Given a language $L=\{E, =\}$ where $E$ is an equivalence relation.

Why does the statement $(\forall y)({\sim}Exy)$ have no quantifier-free formulation? Isn't: $$({\sim}Exa \mathbin\& {\sim}Exb \mathbin\& {\sim}Exc \ldots{\sim}Exn)$$ where $\{a, b, c,\ldots, n\}$ are all the objects in the universe, such a formulation?

According to my professor, the above statement has no quantifier-free formulation. Why isn't a simple conjunction sufficient? Because it could be infinite?

(I guess ignore that there is a $y$ such that $Exy$, namely $x$ itself?)

Comment: If your universe is finite, you can enumerate all its inhabitants. Otherwise, you need a quantifier.

Comment: I don't see how you can ignore the fact that equivalence relations are reflexive (i.e., $E(x, x)$ holds fory any $x$). Either (1) you are talking about equivalence in the theory of an equivalence relation, in which case $\forall y\cdot \lnot E(x, y)$ is false and so is equivalent to $\lnot x = x$ or (2) you are talking about the theory of an arbitrary binary relation, in which case why does the phrase "*where $E$ is an equivalence relation*" appear in your question?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: When not using any TeX-like processing `~` makes a reasonable replacement for negation. Why bother keeping it if you use MathJax which has `\neg` and `\lnot`?

Comment: @Asaf I do that solely to avoid alienating the OP from their own question.

Answer (score 3):

There are several potential issues here, and exactly which ones are relevant depends on the exact formalism you're using.

First, if your language is exactly $\{E,=\}$ then in the usual formulation of first-order logic, "$\sim Exa$" where $a$ is an object in your universe isn't actually a formula.  (There are easy ways around this---for instance, adding a constant symbol for each object in your universe---so this may not be a serious obstacle in your set-up.)

Second, and this is the most important reason, talking about an equivalent formula often means the formula should be equivalent in all universes, not just in one.  The formula you've written down *is* equivalent to $\forall y\ \mathop{\sim}Exy$ in that particular universe (assuming it's finite), but it won't work in any other universe.

Finally, as you noticed, if the universe is infinite, you'd need an infinite conjunction, which is no longer a first-order formula.